# Filtering and displaying specific lines from a log file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filter, criteria, logfile

I have a system generated log file, which includes values such as approvals and rejections transactions line by line on daily basis every 30 minutes, we require to extract and print the line of rejected transaction, currently this log file goes above 200 to 300 lines and we have to manually check the logs. Is there a way in PowerShell where I can just print the rejected values in the file eg:

logfile (actual)
[08:03:33] 1209031,,,,,status,trnasaction, requested
[08:04:33] 1548215,,,,,status,trnasaction, response
[08:06:33] 1852415,,,,,status,trnasaction, **Rejected**
[08:09:33] 1685941,,,,,status,trnasaction, approved
[08:11:33] 1548215,,,,,status,trnasaction, response
[08:15:33] 1852415,,,,,status,A73IF4DE5,heartbeat, **Rejected**
[08:21:33] 1685941,,,,,status,,transaction, **Rejected**

logfile (output)
[08:06:33] 1852415,,,,,status,trnasaction, **Rejected**
[08:15:33] 1852415,,,,,status,A73IF4DE5,heartbeat, **Rejected**
[08:21:33] 1685941,,,,,status,,transaction, **Rejected**

Comment: There sure is, one method is using `Get-Content` with the `-match` operator which allows for RegEx. Another being the `switch` statement with a `-RegEx` switch, or even using a `-Like` instead. Happy to help if you can come up with some code on your own.

Comment: Have a look at [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself. Note this is *not* a script factory. You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers (knowing that there are really a lot of [PowerShell log filtering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PowerShell+log+file+filter)), you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the log in a variable with Get-Content and then you can filter with Select-String, below a little example:

```
$Log = get-content "Your_Log_File"
$Log | Select-String "Rejected"
```

Comment: In PowerShell, you better *not* put the results in a variable but stream it through the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines): `get-content  .\file.log |Select-String 'Rejected' |...`